# laravel - how can I call a function stored in a controller after saving to a database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm following a tutorial on Laravel, adding to a DB via a form. At the end of a function that saves to a DB, it returns back to the page where the form is, but I want to be taken to another page where the information is displayed. In the tutorial I created a controller with a function that returns a view containing all the database info - that element works fine however I can't seem to find a way of calling this function directly after saving to the database. I can also return any other view which just displays static view ( just html with no data handling ). Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

```
  public function store(){        

        $li = new \App\LTest1();
        $li->creator = request('creator');
        $li->title = request('title');
        $li->views = request('views');
        $li->save();
        return back(); // this works
       // return view('info');  // this works
       //return ('Listings@showList');   this doesnt work = how do i call a function in a controller???
    }
// routing

Route::get('info', function () {
    return view('info'); // i can get to this static page from my store() function
});

Route::get('thedataviewpage', 'Listings@showList'); // you can route to this but not from the store() function
```

Comment: `return redirect('info');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects) is the thing you need here

```
public function store() {
    $li = new \App\LTest1();
    $li->creator = request('creator');
    $li->title = request('title');
    $li->views = request('views');
    $li->save();

    return redirect('info'); // Redirect to the info route
}
```

Comment: I just had to change the redirect to say the route I wanted and it worked . Now it seems so simple - massive thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take this example. Be sure to add the proper route name and a proper message.

`return redirect()->route('put here the route name')->with('success', 'Created.');'`

Answer (score 0):

to return to a controller action just use

```
return redirect()->action('Listings@showList');
```

or you can use route to call that controller action

```
return redirect('/thedataviewpage');
```